# Is there a way to create category in flutter and firestore

Tags: flutter

### I'm creating category section for my shop app in flutter with firestore, which I have been able to retrieve all category in a listview but I want to know how I can retrieve each category collection when I onTap it. Thanks

This the code have written  for changeNotifier and firestore query

```
 class CategoryNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
      List<Category> _categoryList = [];
      Category _currentCategory;

      UnmodifiableListView<Category> get categoryList => UnmodifiableListView(_categoryList);

      Category get currentCategory => _currentCategory;

      set categoryList(List<Category> categoryList){
        _categoryList = categoryList;
        notifyListeners();
      }

      set currentCategory(Category category){
        _currentCategory = category;
        notifyListeners();
      }
    }

    getCategory(CategoryNotifier categoryNotifier)async{
      QuerySnapshot snapshot = await Firestore
          .instance.collection("Categories")
          .getDocuments();

      List<Category> _categoryList = [];


      snapshot.documents.forEach((document){
        Category category = Category.fromMap(document.data);
        _categoryList.add(category);

      });

      categoryNotifier.categoryList = _categoryList;
    }
```

> This is the code for retrieving all categories from firestore in
>   horizontal listview

```
    class HorizontalCategoryWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      const HorizontalCategoryWidget({
        Key key,
        @required this.categoryNotifier
      }) : super(key: key);

      final CategoryNotifier categoryNotifier;

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return ListView.builder(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: categoryNotifier.categoryList.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 80,
                child: GestureDetector(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4),
                          height: 40,
                          width: 80.0,
                          child: FadeInImage(
                            placeholder: AssetImage('assets/tsplaceholder.png'),
                            image: NetworkImage( categoryNotifier.categoryList[index].icon),
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(height: 4,),
                        Text(
                          categoryNotifier.categoryList[index].categoryName,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          maxLines: 1,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                    onTap: () {

                    }),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      }
    }
```

[image: fsdb]

Comment: If i am understanding your question correctly you want to retrieve a particular document inside your category collection when the user clicks on it ???

Comment: I have been able to retrieve all the documents under category . Each document Id has a subCollection that's what I want to retrieve when when I onTap on it.. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: [Please refer to this link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13058), you can do it like this.```db.collection("Collection").document("Document").getCollections()``` this method basically return all the subcollection inside the document, if you need any help let me know